# Print result probability for each row in Naive Bayes algorithm

Tags: python, jupyter, naivebayes

i am working in a clasification problem
how can i use this function to print the probability of the resulted class
predict_proba(txt)

Comment: Is this is a NLP task? (Given your mention of `txt` as a variable.) Or, what is `txt` in this case?

Comment: Yes it is. This is  the script:                                                                                   
   def NB_clf(x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test):
    clf                     = GaussianNB()clf.fit(x_train.toarray(),y_train)
    
    print(clf.predict_proba(x_test.toarray()))
 NB_clf(x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test)

i got this output: zeros and ones!!

[[0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 ...
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]


How can I show the probabilties for example 88. 67, 96, .... etc